# cannot use SUNDIALS-KINSOL in FORTRAN subroutine?

Tags: fortran

Thank you for having a look at this problem.

**Problem:**
seg. fault when returning from f90 subroutine that contains KINSOL solving process, *after* the *correct* computation result has been generated. No problem when the same solving process is in the main program.

**Environment:**
linux,
gcc,
sundials static libs

**How to initiate the problem:**

get the attached REDUCED test code

```
module moduleNonlinearSolve
  integer,save::nEq
contains
  subroutine solveNonlinear(u)
    double precision::u(*)
    integer iout(15),ier
    double precision rout(2),koefScal(nEq)
    koefScal(:)=1d0
    call fnvinits(3,nEq,ier)
    call fkinmalloc(iout,rout,ier)
    call fkinspgmr(50,10,ier)
    call fkinsol(u,1,koefScal,koefScal,ier)
    call fkinfree()
    do i=1,nEq
      write(*,*),i,u(i)
    end do
  end subroutine
end module

subroutine fkfun(u,fval,ier)
  use moduleNonlinearSolve
  double precision::u(*)
  double precision::fval(*)
  integer::ier
  forall(i=2:nEq-1)
    fval(i)=-u(i-1)+2d0*u(i)-u(i+1)-1d0
  end forall
  fval(1)=u(1)+2d0*u(1)-u(2)-1d0
  fval(nEq)=-u(nEq-1)+2d0*u(nEq)+u(nEq)-1d0
  ier=0
end subroutine

program test
  use moduleNonLinearSolve
  double precision u(10)
  nEq=size(u)
  u(:)=10d0
  call solveNonlinear(u)
end program``
```

compile

```
$ gfortran -c -Wall -g test.f90
$ gfortran -Wall -g -o test test.o -lsundials_fkinsol -lsundials_fnvecserial -lsundials_kinsol -lsundials_nvecserial -llapack -lblas
```

run

```
$ ./test
```

**Note: It would work flawlessly if put all the SUNDIALS procedures in the main program.**

Thank you very much for any input.

Mianzhi

Comment: Why have you included the source of `fkfun` ?  I don't see it being called anywhere.

Comment: The fkfun is an external function called by KINSOL. Actually the purpose of KINSOL is to solve the nonlinear system of equations "fkfun=0". This link-time problem definition method is also used by other FORTRAN nonlinear solvers. @HighPerformanceMark

Comment: Do you have any interface for the KINSOL routines? Check it carefully.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is, but perhaps adding `implicit none` to your functions may reveal a type problem?

Comment: What is the size of the C type `long int` on your machine?

Comment: implicit none does not reveal unexpected type problem @amaurea

Comment: i don't think there are mismatch of type size. because it works fine in main program, only seg fault when returning from subroutine. @amaurea

Comment: size of long int is 8 @amaurea

Comment: bit size of FORTRAN integer is          32 @amaurea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [KINSOL](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/documentation/kin_guide.pdf) documentation, the first argument of `fkinmalloc` must be of the same integer type as the `C` type `long int`. In your case, `long int` is 8 bytes long, but you are passing in an array of 4 byte integers. This will lead to `fkinmalloc` trying to write beyond the bounds of the array, and into some other memory. This typically leads to memory corruption, which has symptoms just like what you are observing: Crash at some random later point, such as when returning from a function. You should be able to confirm this by running the program through valgrind, which will probably report invalid writes of size 8. Anyway, replacing

```
integer :: iout(15)
```

with

```
integer*8 :: iout(15)
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. I should have learned to use valgrind. @amaurea